# Hover applying outside image

Tags: html, css

[Here image hover not closing outside image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zicvi.jpg)[Departments dropdown not clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu58x.jpg)

```css
.post{
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  position:relative; 
  cursor: pointer;
}
.post:hover .post-s{
  margin-top: 7%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 90%;
}
.post img{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 7%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.post-s{
  margin-top: 7%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  border-radius: 20px;
   width: 0px;
  height: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(103, 58, 183, 0.71);
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: 0.7s ease;
}
.post-s p{
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Sofia';
  font-size: 35;
  border: 6px solid white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post" class="zoomimage">
            <img src="https://gymkhana.iitb.ac.in/~nss/assets/images/EventsBG.png" alt="Eventimg">

            <div class="post-s">
                <p>John DoeEvents tries to make sure that our services to mankind find their destination. The department is very versatile with regard to the kind of activities contributing towards the upliftment of society. Helping the underprivileged by providing them with necessary amenities can be attributed as the cornerstone of what we do. Ranging from welfare of construction workers to spreading awareness about various social problems through blogs and street plays, NSS Events aims to serve the society in the most satisfying ways.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

## Image hover running ouside image when curser is outside image?

Due to hover applying outside image boundary my nav dropdown also not running due to hover applying over this soo what to do for this
[here is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu58x.jpg)

Comment: The part with the hover on covers the whole screen. Do you have a navigation above the code you posted?

Comment: Yes I have dopdown content in department section and and partner NGOs has link but hovering cover whole screen

Comment: Will you add the department section as well? You only have the hover part in.

Comment: I think this problem is coming due to   margin-top: 7%;
  margin-left: 10%; these i added in .post-s & .post:hover so can i do any alternative??

Comment: Just need more info. Do you have a navigation and then directly underneath that you have this hover box? Is your navigation positioned absolute or fixed?

Comment: My navigation is absolute i have navigation used unordered list type and hover box used text over that image

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Been on holiday. I think your content area is covering the navigation because of the absolute positioning. Absolute takes the space that it would normally have taken out of the DOM. You can add a padding top to the body or a margin top to the content area to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.post{
  width: 90%;
     height: 70%;
  position:relative; 
  cursor: pointer;
}
.post:hover .post-s{
  margin-top: 7%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 89%;
}
.post img{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 7%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.post-s{
  margin-top: 7%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  border-radius: 20px;
   width: 0px;
  height: 89%;
   background-color: rgba(103, 58, 183, 0.71);
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: 0.7s ease;
}
.post-s p{
      margin: 0 1px 0 1px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Sofia';
  font-size: 35;
  border: 6px solid white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post" class="zoomimage">
            <img src="https://gymkhana.iitb.ac.in/~nss/assets/images/EventsBG.png" alt="Eventimg">

            <div class="post-s">
                <p>John DoeEvents tries to make sure that our services to mankind find their destination. The department is very versatile with regard to the kind of activities contributing towards the upliftment of society. Helping the underprivileged by providing them with necessary amenities can be attributed as the cornerstone of what we do. Ranging from welfare of construction workers to spreading awareness about various social problems through blogs and street plays, NSS Events aims to serve the society in the most satisfying ways.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```